# sort files by word in a line

Tags: bash, sorting

I have several files which look like this. I want to sort them by their px numbers- ascending or descending to see the file with the best px value.

```
8671 words (including </s>), 8671 decompounded words
 816 sentence(s), -llh=35158.3217 px=11342.3246, 323 oov (4.11%)
 1-gram hits: 5537 (63.86%)
 2-gram hits: 2859 (32.97%)
 3-gram hits: 258 (2.98%)
 4-gram hits: 17 (0.20%)
```

Is there any way to use the sort commmand by their px number?(px=11342.3246)

Comment: There is only one line with a px value. Do you want to sort **records**?

Comment: I have several files which look like this. I want to sort them by their px numbers- ascending or descending to see the file with the best px value.

Comment: Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where I would use both `grep` and `sed` in a single pipeline, since getting hold of the file name is tricky in `sed`:

```
grep px= my_files* | sed -r 's/([^:]+):.*px=([0-9.]+).*/\2 \1/' | sort -n
```